# Retrieve search results | PHP & SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, variables

I have a table created with all the fields necessary like (ID, Name, surname, etc.)

In search php file, when you type the ID it shows you all the information corresponding of this ID, e.g. (ID=1, name=Jack)

MY IDEA: When i do a custom search, inside the php I want to add a link to another php file that shows the same search result but with additional info.

QUESTION: How can I call to a custom search result from other php file?

Regarding this example, If I search for ID=2, I want to link to another php file "Extrainfo.php" that shows more info of that custom search.

Here is the code I used:

```
//database connection

global $conn;
$servername = "localhost";  //host name
$username = "root"; //username
$password = ""; //password
$mysql_database = "info"; //database name

//mysqli prepared statement 

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

mysqli_select_db($conn,$mysql_database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

if(isset($_GET['idNumber']))
{
    $IDNUMBER =$_GET['idNumber'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from madea where idNumber=? ");
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$IDNUMBER);
    $stmt->execute();
    $val =  $stmt->get_result();
    $row_count= $val->num_rows;

    if($row_count>0)
    {
        $result =$val->fetch_assoc(); 
        echo $result['idNumber']; 
        echo $result['name']; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "identification_number not Match";
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

    // Probably need to save the variable to call in the other php file?

    $idNumber = $result['idNumber']; 

}

?>

<a href="extrainfo.php">Extrainfo</a>
```

Comment: `QUESTION: How can I call to a custom search result from other php file?` Well, you're sending stuff over `$_GET` which isn't advised. But you would `header("Location: page.php?idNumber=search term")`

Comment: @WillParky93 Should I use post method then? Or which way do you suggest me its the best choice.

Many thanks :)

Comment: Yes use post. If you're using post you won't be able to header sufficiently but you could always use `ajax` to query your php pages.

Comment: you want to load the 2nd page as pop when button click or ?

Comment: Just a tip I see your connecting to database on top of page codeigniter has a built in database library all ready for that so you dont have to http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html

Comment: Ok, regarding your first commentary, If I use header, I get back all the php file. Only needed the variables of the search result.

About the code, In search tearm, what exactly should I type to be the same like the current query?

Thanks

Comment: @Sand nope, I need it in a new page.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Yes, I have no problem when I try to connect to database, I have the problem to get back the result search of the query.

Comment: what wolfgang1983 meant is that you should use the mvc paradigm properly - and CI offers a nice toolset for this ;)

Comment: @sintakonte Ok, I will take a look to improve the connection to database via codeigniter parameters. Many thanks for the advice! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally do it by another way.

result.php only added an href that redirects to a moreinfo.php but with the query string of the id number.

```
 <a href="moreinfo.php?idNumber=<?php echo $idNumber?>" class="moreInfo" id="<?php echo $result['idNumber']; ?>" target="_blank">Download PDF INFO</a>
```

And here comes the other part of code in moreinfo.php

At first, get the id number on query string that it previously redirected by the link and get it into a variable to use it after in the sql query

```
$reportNumber = $_GET['idNumber'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM madea where reportNumber='".$idNumber."'");
```

And the rest, only show the results what I really need:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$html .= '<td>'.$row['idNumber'].'</td><td>' . $row['Name']. '</td>';
 }
```

Hope it helps to further issues. So appreciated for all the help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I can show you.

You 1st php,

```
if(isset($_GET['idNumber']))
{
    $IDNUMBER =$_GET['idNumber'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from madea where idNumber=? ");
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$IDNUMBER);
    $stmt->execute();
    $val =  $stmt->get_result();
    $row_count= $val->num_rows;

    if($row_count>0)
    {
        $result =$val->fetch_assoc(); 
        echo $result['idNumber']; 
        echo $result['name'];
        echo "<a href="#" id=".$result['idNumber']." class="moreInfo">More Info</a>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "identification_number not Match";
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

    // Probably need to save the variable to call in the other php file?

    $idNumber = $result['idNumber']; 

}
```

Now I'm using AJAX and Jquery so please link the appropriate libraries.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.moreInfo', function(){
            $.ajax({
            url: 'moreInfo.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'idNumber': $('.moreInfo').prop('id')
            }
            }).then(function (response) {
            $('#morInfoDiv').html(response);
            });
        })
    })
</script>
```

The moreInfo.php,

```
if(isset($_POST['idNumber']))
{
    $IDNUMBER =$_GET['idNumber'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from madea where idNumber=? ");
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$IDNUMBER);
    $stmt->execute();
    $val =  $stmt->get_result();
    $row_count= $val->num_rows;

    if($row_count>0)
    {?>
        Name:<? echo $result['Name']; ?><br>        
        Address:<? echo $result['address']; ?><br>
        Date of Birth:<? echo $result['dob']; ?><br>
    <?php }
    else
    {
        echo "identification_number not Match";
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
}
```

Now in your 1st php file can have a `DIV` which will show the response from the moreInfo.php

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="morInfoDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

AJAX script will send the data in post method then capture the response text from the 2nd PHP and add it to the `DIV` ided as "moreInfo".

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. I tried to do but it show me back

Undefined index (idNumber):  $IDNUMBER =$_GET['idNumber'];
Undefined variable (conn):  $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from madea where idNumber=? ");